# What does setBackground(getBackground()) do?

Tags: jtable, setbackground

From the code snippet...

```
if ((Boolean) getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 4)) {
    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    repaint();
} else {
    c.setBackground(getBackground());
```

If the background is currently Color.GREEN, c.setBackground(getBackground()) seems to reset the background of the cell to the default colour of the table. This is what I want it to do, but I don't understand why. Surely getBackground() returns Color.GREEN, then c.setBackground(getBackground()) sets the background of the cell to green - i.e. it doesn't change.

Could someone please explain what's going on here?

Many thanks,

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the `getBackground()` method is not called under the object `c`

That is - not like this: `c.getBackground()`

Perhaps that is the reason? e.g `getBackground()` simply returns the color of the table? or some default?

Maybe the function is a static one? or of another object? without too much context it is difficult to say for sure..

Comment: Thanks SatA. That sounds plausible to me.